# 指定したファイルパスが存在するか確かめたい

Tags: linux, shellscript

`~/Desktop/animals/cat.txt`

が存在するかコマンドで確かめたい。

存在したら `Found`
存在しなかったら `Not found`
を出力したいです

Comment: testコマンドどぞ～。 http://itpro.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/COLUMN/20060227/230901/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ソース
`[ -e ~/Desktop/animals/cat.txt ]  && echo Found || echo Not found`

出力
`Not found`

オプション

```
-e ファイルかディレクトリが実在するか判定
-f ファイルが実在するか判定
-d ディレクトリが実在するか判定
-x 実行可能ファイルが実在するか判定
-r 読み込み可能か判定
-w 書き込み可能か判定
```

この書き方は `短絡評価` といいます

Comment: ほんとだ。三項演算子ってこんなふうにかけるんだ！！

Comment: 三項演算子ではなく、短絡評価ってやつです。三項演算子likeに使えるってだけですよ。

Comment: 「これは三項演算子の代わりになります」の部分を「この書き方は 短絡評価 といいます」に修正しました

Comment: @豚吐露  さん助かりました。